# Linq / XML - How do you handle non existing nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to figure out how to handle nodes that do not exist for all of my "card" elements. I have the following linq query:

```
    FinalDeck = (from deck in xmlDoc.Root.Element("Cards")
                    .Elements("Card")
                    select new CardDeck
                    {
                        Name = deck.Attribute("name").Value,
                        Image = deck.Element("Image").Attribute("path").Value,
                        Usage = (int)deck.Element("Usage"),
                        Type = deck.Element("Type").Value,
                        Strength = (int)deck.Element("Ability") ?? 0
                    }).ToList();
```

with the Strength item, I had read another posting that the ?? handles the null. I am getting the following error though:

Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

How do I handle this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use the `Value` property, cast to `string`... and for the `int`, cast to `int?` instead. The user defined conversions to nullable types will return null if the source `XAttribute`/`XElement` is null:

```
FinalDeck = (from deck in xmlDoc.Root.Element("Cards")
                .Elements("Card")
                select new CardDeck
                {
                    Name = (string) deck.Attribute("name"),
                    Image = (string) deck.Element("Image").Attribute("path"),
                    Usage = (int?) deck.Element("Usage"),
                    Type = (string) deck.Element("Type"),
                    Strength = (int?) deck.Element("Ability") ?? 0
                }).ToList();
```

Note that this *won't* help for the case where the `Image` element is missing, as then it'll try to dereference a null element to find the `path` attribute. Let me know if you want a workaround for that, but it'll be a bit of a pain, relatively speaking.

EDIT: You can always create an extension method for this yourself:

```
public static XAttribute NullSafeAttribute(this XElement element, XName name)
{
    return element == null ? null : element.Attribute(name);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Image = (string) deck.Element("Image").NullSafeAttribute("path"),
```

Comment: That fixed it! Would you mind explaining exactly what the int? does?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: In the case of the image it will always be there. But why does it not work with attribute? I can see this being an issue once I start to develop my XML more.

Comment: @Stacey: It's fine for attributes in general - but you're trying to find a subelement and then the attribute *of that element*. There may be an extension method you could call on XElement to return an XAttribute or null if the XElement is null. Will add an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will definately keep this in mind as I start to expand my XML.